# Prerequisites/limitations using Person Accounts with MC Connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

are there any Prerequisites/limitations or things to definitely watch out for when integrating the Marketing Cloud to a Sales Cloud where Person Accounts are being used instead of regular contacts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some considerations when setting up Marketing Cloud Connect, sure, but in general it's fairly straightforward and out of the box setup.

Overall, Marketing Cloud is intended to be B2C communication tool, so all the functionalities fully support Person Accounts and their behavior in Sales Cloud. It's just not fully LEX ready if anything.

The main things to take into account are:

- It will be the Person Account Contact record that is used in interactions and outbound communication, **not** the Person Account record.
- You should update the Person Account layout in Sales Cloud to add Related Lists for Individual Email Sends, Email Messages, buttons for Unsubscribe/Resubscribe.
- For Personalization and Sales Cloud datamodel, you should synchronise Account and Contact objects with Marketing Cloud Connect.
- Each Lead, User and Contact - either from B2C or B2B account will be counted as unique, billable system contact in Marketing Cloud.
- Standard (non-configurable) field to track the subscription status will be EmailOptOut field on Sales Cloud, this field status will match with the subscribers status in Email Studio AllSubscribers list. However, updating this field manually in Sales Cloud will not trigger an update to Marketing Cloud - use the Unsubscribe/Resubscribe buttons in Sales Cloud for that.
- [Configuring Salesforce Data Entry events with Person Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_configure_events_for_person_accounts.htm&type=5)

Comment: I would also add a custom field to the Person Account Page Layout, which shows the related PersonContactId, as you will no longer be able to view the Contact Page Layout.

Comment: @JonasLamberty thanks, did that :)